# kafka broker memory imbalance

Tags: memory, apache-kafka, mmap, broker

We have a three-node Kafka cluster with the machine configuration:

- node0 32core 128g
- node1 4core 8g
- node2 32core 128g
  Only XMS is configured for all three nodes and XMX is not specified
  But after a while,
- Node0 occupies 12.7 GB of memory
  [Node0 top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBwIk.png)
- Node1 occupies 2.1 GB of memory
  [Node1 top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzVSB.png)
- Node2 occupies 3.1g memory
  [Node2 top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYGm9.png)

For node1, the JVM XMX defaults to 25% of the machine's memory
Arthas has the following memory information for node0:
[node jvm dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjF2q.png)
In arthas's dashboard, node0's heap memory footprint is similar to node2's, but the MMAP portion is much larger.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the memory usage of kafka's three nodes so different?
2. Why is node0's RES memory smaller than Arthas's in-heap + out-of-heap sum